# Alternative solution to python multi-level group by for creating new variables in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, group-by, apply

I am trying to create a function which creates new variables in a DataFrame based on multi-level variable grouping.
The below patch satisfactorily produce the desired result, however the execution time is on the higher side for a run-time environment.

Can anyone suggest a better alternative ?

```
def prob_calc(test1):
    test1["log_sum"] = np.log(sum(np.exp(test1.utility)))
    test1["prob_logit_within_nest"] = np.exp(test1.utility)/sum(np.exp(test1.utility))
    test1["Freq_of_nest"] = sum(test1.flag)
    return test1
test1 = test1.groupby(['quest_number','task','nest']).apply(prob_calc)
```

Thanks,
Sombit

Comment: Can you provide sample desired inputs and outputs?

Comment: The input for the function is a data-frame (test1). It has the variables like 'utility', 'flag', 'quest_number', 'task', 'nest'.  
The desired output should be the same data-frame with additional columns like 'log_sum', 'prob_logit_within_nest' & 'Freq_of_nest'.
We need to group it by the listed grouping varibales.

Comment: Please provide this so we can easily copy and paste it for experimenting. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples